# Caching Large Dataframes in Spark Effectively

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working on 11,000 files. Each file will generate a data frame which will be Union with the previous one. Below is the code:

```
var df1 = sc.parallelize(Array(("temp",100 ))).toDF("key","value").withColumn("Filename", lit("Temp") )     
files.foreach( filename => {
             val a = filename.getPath.toString()
             val m = a.split("/")
             val name = m(6)
             println("FILENAME: " + name)                
             if (name == "_SUCCESS") {
               println("Cannot Process '_SUCCSS' Filename")
             } else {
               val freqs=doSomething(a).toDF("key","value").withColumn("Filename", lit(name) )
               df1=df1.unionAll(freqs)
             }

})
```

First, i got an error of `java.lang.StackOverFlowError` on 11,000 files. Then, i add a following line after `df1=df1.unionAll(freqs)`:

```
 df1=df1.cache()
```

It resolves the problem but after each iteration, it is getting slower. Can somebody please suggest me what should be done to avoid `StackOverflowError` with no decrease in time.
Thanks!

Comment: The lineage becomes very deep and thus inefficient. You could try to `checkpoint` to truncate the lineage (in Spark 2). Alternatively, you could write all individual dataframes to disk (e.g. in a table which is partitioned by filename)...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that spark manages a dataframe as a set of transformations. It begins with the "toDF" of the first dataframe, then perform the transformations on it (e.g. withColumn), then unionAll with the previous dataframe etc.

The unionAll is just another such transformation and the tree becomes very long (with 11K unionAll you have an execution tree of depth 11K). The unionAll when building the information can get to a stack overflow situation.

The caching doesn't solve this, however, I imagine you are adding some action along the way (otherwise nothing would run besides building the transformations). When you perform caching, spark might skip some of the steps and therefor the stack overflow would simply arrive later.

You can go back to RDD for iterative process (your example actually is not iterative but purely parallel, you can simply save each separate dataframe along the way and then convert to RDD and use RDD union).

Since your case seems to be join unioning a bunch of dataframes without true iterations, you can also do the union in a tree manner (i.e. union pairs, then union pairs of pairs etc.) this would change the depth from O(N) to O(log N) where N is the number of unions.

Lastly, you can read and write the dataframe to/from disk. The idea is that after every X (e.g. 20) unions, you would do df1.write.parquet(filex) and then df1 = spark.read.parquet(filex). When you read the lineage of a single dataframe would be the file reading itself. The cost of course would be the writing and reading of the file.

Comment: I am new to spark and still very confused. can you please provide a code of Union in tree manner and how parquet will work with this parallel iteration? Thanks @AssafMendelson

Comment: Don't have code available off hand, but the idea is that you loop through the vector of dataframes doing a union: df(i).union(df(i+1)). This would result in a vector with half the number of elements. Then repeat this process until you get one dataframe.